# Exporting data in raw format in R

Tags: r, import, export

I will briefly describe my problem in here...
I am working with Access database file (.accdb), due to some compatibility issues I had to run 32 bit version of R to access the database and import data. I have imported the data but when I try to do some operations on the data file (merging) I run into an error

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 152.1 Mb
```

So my solution for this is, import the data using 32bit version and run the program in 64bit version. (Is there any better way to do this ??)

My question is what is the best way to export data from R? I dont want to export them into excel/csv files as writing/reading them will again consume a lot of time. How do I export raw data in R and how do import this data into my new environment (64 bit )? Or is there any better method to do this?

Comment: Are you running MS Office in 32-bit? An .accdb file can work in 64-bit environments. Are you using RODBC? Please show connection string.

Comment: Yeah, I am using ROBDC and my office is 64bit, but the drivers for .accdb are 32 bit, so I couldnt run it on 64 bit R                                    

    connection <- odbcConnect("Database_name")

Comment: I bet you do have 64-bit drivers. Check odbcad32.exe in the `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64` folder. Also, try the more general connection: `conn <-odbcDriverConnect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Path\\To\\Database\\File.accdb')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 32 bit:

```
save(list=ls(), file='~/r_workspace.RData')
```

and then in 64 bit:

```
load(file='~/r_workspace.RData')
```